# DXA 2.2 Issue with Publication Title

Tags: dxa, templating, dxa2.2

We have noticed that if there is `.` and `/` character in Publication Title, DXA template throw error while publishing/previewing the pages. Find below error message:

```
(80040200) An error occurred while rendering Page '000 Home' (tcm:162-90394-64)
Unable to load include page for 'system/include/header'
No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/090%20test%2Ecom/en-US%20%28DXA%29/root/_System/include/Header.tpg.

No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/090%20test%2Ecom/en-US%20%28DXA%29/root/_System/include/Header.tpg.
```

Here Publication title is 090 test.com/en-US (DXA) whose WebDAV should be `090%20test.com%2Fen-US%20%28DXA%29`. Wondering if anyone noticed this issue and have some quick workaround? I know we can change the Template code but wondering if there is any other fix as well? If I change the Publication title to remove `.` and `/`, it's started working fine.

**Update:**

We have tried following steps mentioned in the DXA 2.2 documentation [URL](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-5E88B1FC-FA9A-46F0-B7A5-89FCF058DB23) to add Webdav URL instead of relative URL, but still no luck. It's still showing the similar error.

```
(80040200) An error occurred while rendering Page '000 Home' (tcm:162-90394-64)
Unable to load include page for '/webdav/090 test.com/en-US (DXA)/root/_System/include/Header.tpg'
No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/090%20test%2Ecom/en-US%20%28DXA%29/root/_System/include/Header.tpg.

No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/090%20test%2Ecom/en-US%20%28DXA%29/root/_System/include/Header.tpg.
```

After adding Page tcm URI in page template, issue got fixed.

I am wondering if Include page tcm URI in page template create some issue as this tcm URI will be incorrect for inherited child publications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re suffering from this Known Issue: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-069E6E6E-7296-4E79-BF75-E3729BC915C8

See also https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-E709D04C-36D8-4666-A9D6-A1759C162FF3

Comment: we tried the steps to add webdav URL in page template but still facing the same issue. With Page tcm URI it's working fine. I have updated my question with error log. I am wondering if adding webdav or page tcm URI creates issue in inherited child publications as these values will be wrong there.

Comment: You should  properly URL-encode the slash character in the Publication title. There won’t be issues in child Publications; see the docs topic (2nd).